# Is it possible to access the applied filters at List Component rendering time

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin-on-rest and i'm in a case where i have to change the column set in a list view according to the applied filters.

Is there any way i can get the currently applied filters so i can do some kind of conditional rendering?

Example:

```
export const AssetList = (props) => (
(!props.filters.includes('group_by') ?
  <List title="Assets" filters={<AssetFilter/>} {...props}>
      <Datagrid>
          <TextField source="asset_uid" />
          <TextField source="amounts.price" label="Price" />
          <ChipListField source="flags" />
          <EditButton />
      </Datagrid>
  </List>
:
  <List title="Assets" filters={<AssetFilter/>} {...props}>
      <Datagrid>
          <TextField source="group_id" />
          <ChipField source="flag_counts.flag1" label="virtual" />
          <ChipField source="flag_counts.flag2" label="operational" />
          <TextField source="total_amounts.price" label="Price" />
          <EditButton />
      </Datagrid>
  </List>)
);
```

Currently there is no such thing as `props.filters` is there any way i can access them ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get filters based on admin-on-rest resources from another resource. You need to `connect` the component and access the filter like this in `mapStateToProps`.
Then you can access it as `this.props.eventFilters` in your component.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    eventFilters:  state.admin.resources.myEventsResource.list.params.filter
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```